# Installing dependencies of a package with Composer

Tags: php, continuous-integration, composer-php

I have a package which is an extension to some wiki software that has several dependencies and can be installed into this wiki software using [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/).

I'm using Jenkins for CI and when a commit gets submitted to my code review system, Jenkins gets the corresponding modified version of the extension. Now I'd like to install the dependencies of this extension in my wiki software. As in, only the dependencies, without the actual package, as I already have this.

Is that possible? Is there another easy way to get my CI setup to use Composer?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you check out your wiki extension from the repository, you should run `composer install` right after it.

If you have the necessary toolset installed, you can download these dependencies anywhere, whenever you locate the main `composer.json` file. Do not confuse that file with all those probably included in the referenced software - you'd find a lot of `composer.json` files in the generated `vendor` folder, because they are also used to identify usable software libraries, not only as a list of dependencies.